# How do I used matched arguments in elixir functions

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

Say I have two use cases for a function. Do something with users that have a subscription and something with users that don't have a subscriptions.

```
def add_subscription(subscription_id, %User{subscription: nil})
  # Do something with user here.
```

And

```
def add_subscription(subscription_id, user)
```

How do I do pattern matching like this and also still use the user in the first function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can bind the function argument to a variable:

```
def add_subscription(subscription_id, %User{subscription: nil} = user)
```

The convention is to assign after the pattern match:

```
# Do This
def foo(%User{subscription: nil} = user)

# Instead of this
def foo(user = %User{subscription: nil})
```

Comment: Is the reason that you do NOT do `def foo(user = %User{subscription: nil})` because that would assign `user` to the right hand side?

Comment: @cogle There is technical reason why you can't do it. It'll bind user in either case. If you do this outside of a pattern match though, then `user = %User{...} will assign user, whereas `%User{...} = user` will pattern match.