# What is the equal sign within a function parameter in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have defined a `Foo` module like this:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def hello(x = %{name: name}) do
    IO.inspect [x, name]
  end
end
```

If I run the `Foo.hello(%{name: "Alice"})`, I get the following result:

```
[%{name: "Alice"}, "Alice"]
```

Then, I learned that I can rewrite the `Foo` module without changing its functionality like this:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def hello(%{name: name} = x) do
    IO.inspect [x, name]
  end
end
```

Why this is possible? What is the equal sign within a function parameter? Is it a normal match operator?

In my understanding, the operator `=` matches the value on the right side against the pattern on the left side.

[Edit]

After reading Justin's answer, I posted an answer by myself. But, I still need help.

I want to know whether the `=` operator does behave differently within the function head and why.

And I want to find an official documentation if available.

Comment: I just to make sure that we're on the same page around what you say after `In my understanding...` and make it a little clearer for anyone reading your question:

With pattern matching, Elixir always tries to make the left hand side the same as the right hand side. Elixir will only change the value of a variable that is on the left hand side of the match operator.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed still the match operator.

The reason you can do this is the same reason you can match like this

```
iex(1)> 1 = x

** (CompileError) iex:3: undefined function x/0
iex(2)> x = 1
1
iex(3)> 1 = x
1
```

Inside your function head, `x` has a value as soon as you use the function and pass an argument into it (same reason you can define the function as `def hello(x) do ... end`). Which means you are allowed to use it on the right hand side of the match operator.

Comment: Thanks. But, on the second `Foo` module, why the given argument is bound to the `x` in the first place? Is this because the `x` is located on the right side of the operator `=`? I am not yet sure the whole mechanism of value binding to the function parameters.

Comment: `x` has a value as soon as you pass something into the function whether it is on the left or right hand side. Like I said, it is no different from when you `def hello(x) do ... end`. The "top level" variable gets assigned to whatever you pass into your function.

Answer (score 3):

After googling for a while, I found an explanation on http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions.

This article refers an *Erlang* fuction:

```
valid_time({Date = {Y,M,D}, Time = {H,Min,S}}) ->
  io:format("The Date tuple (~p) says today is: ~p/~p/~p,~n",[Date,Y,M,D]),
  io:format("The time tuple (~p) indicates: ~p:~p:~p.~n", [Time,H,Min,S]);
```

Then it says:

> Note that it is possible to use the `=` operator in the function head, allowing us to match both the content inside a tuple (`{Y,M,D}`) and the tuple as a whole (`Date`).

It is about *Erlang*, but It seems the mechanism is the same on Elixir.

For experiment, I rewrote the `Foo` module as follows:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def hello(%{name: x} = %{name: y}) do
    IO.inspect [x, y]
  end
end
```

Then I ran the `Foo.hello(%{name: "Alice"})`, and got this:

```
["Alice", "Alice"]
```

The pattern matching on the argument is done against two patterns on *both* sides of the `=` operator.

Comment: This answer should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36184075/3741729